# Selection of vertices in a complex model

Tags: texturing, vertex-groups

I have a textured complex model with a lot of vertices. I would like to select a shape in the model and put those vertices in a *Vertex Group*. The issue I'm facing is when I go to *Edit Mode*, I can't see the texture and can't select my desired vertices. I tried texture mode in "edit mode" to no avail. I have to zoom in a lot to see the texture. Any fix for this? Also is there any technique to select vertices based on texture features like color?

As in the screenshots, the texture is not visible in the *Edit Mode*, but hardly visible when zoomed in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That sounds really strange. Can you edit the question and use Stackexchange’s built-in image adding system to post screenshots? (please don’t photograph your monitor)

Comment: You might be able to use the texture itself to select the vertices. Would that be any help?

Comment: @RobinBetts I have no idea about that. Any related links?

Comment: I've just been trying it out with GN. Unfortunately, it doesn't include HSV in its color nodes, which would be handy for this. We could make our own, but I don't know whether it's worth it for this job. Could you share the image / significant sample of it /  somewhere? Watermarked, or whatever is good for you?